# What is POPULAR today when it comes to write SQL Queries: UPPER CASE or Lower Case?

Tags: sql, t-sql, conventions, uppercase, lowercase

What is POPULAR today when it comes to write SQL Queries: UPPER CASE or Lower Case? And for what specific reason?

```
SELECT * FROM tMyTable
```

Or

```
Select * from tMytable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either. Just be consistent

*Personally*...

Keywords uppercase for me, objects and datatypes in Normal or CapsCase.

```
SELECT 
    M.Column1,
    CAST(O.Column2 AS int) AS IntColumn
FROM
    MyTable M
    JOIN
    OtherTable O ON M.SomeKey = O.SomeKey 
WHERE
    M.Column3 = 'bar'
ORDER BY
    M.Column1
```

It's easier to pick out the clauses of a complete SELECT query this way

Comment: I totally agree here, prefering the keywords uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

As for me, it's a question of personal preferences. i prefer lower case. i don't like when sql-statements shout on me)

Answer (score 0):

Case is not usually important within an SQL statement. Often people capitalise keywords just to make them stand out. IMHO, consistancy of choice just makes your code easier to read, although, I would rather have capitalised keywords, myself.